# How to add new key value pair to request.env object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails controller following two lines of code are being used.

```
security_data = request.env['HTTP_X_SECURITY_DATA']
security_hash = request.env['HTTP_X_SECURITY_HASH']
```

I want to understand how/when/where these keys **HTTP_X_SECURITY_DATA** and **HTTP_X_SECURITY_HASH** are set to **request.env** hash or object.

I have read through [this](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/25-rails-request-environment-variables) blog, but I did not get how to add new key-value of our own.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add or delete any key in `env` by creating a middleware app:

```
class AddHeaderMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env['YOUR_KEY_HERE'] = 'your_value'
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    [@status, @headers, @response]
  end
end
```

You can add key to `env` inside `call` method.

Comment: Don't forget to register this middleware in `application.rb` (or environment specific configuration) file. Like: `config.middleware.use "AddHeaderMiddleware"`.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should use `@status, @headers, @response` variables, You can directly return `@app.call(env)`, as it returns an array.